# jQuery click to show a div

Tags: jquery, html, onclick

My jquery is not working, I'm using this HTML:

```
            <div id="first_link"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Link</a></div>
            <div id="first_div" style="display: none;">
                Div content
            </div>
```

and I'm using this jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $("#first_link").on('click', function(){
        $('#first_div).fadeIn("fast");
    });
});
```

Comment: You're missing quotes.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo

Comment: @ user: It's *really useful* to look in the web console of your browser. It'll tell you useful things, like the fact you have a simple syntax error. It'll even tell you where that syntax error is, usually. *Edit:* This wasn't a reply to your question above, we overlapped. But replying: Not using basic debugging tools qualifies as a lack of research effort, so that's probably why the question was downvoted.

Comment: I understand but actually I'm unable to find where is console in browser :(

Comment: Oh! You can google if you don't know how to use browser?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're missing a `'` in `$('#first_div).fadeIn("fast");`

try this jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $("#first_link").on('click', function(){
        $('#first_div').fadeIn("fast");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $('#first_link').on('click', function(){
        $('#first_div').fadeIn('fast');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('#first_div).fadeIn("fast");
```

missing closing `'`

should be :

```
$('#first_div').fadeIn("fast");
```

Answer (score 0):

missing quote `'`

```
  $('#first_div).fadeIn("fast");
```

change it to

```
   $('#first_div').fadeIn("fast");
```